# could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution on distro

Tags: postgresql, docker, fastapi

I'am starting docker compose running docker on linux

When is starting docker + fastapi + postgresql i have error:

```
web_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1  | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
web_1  | 
web_1  | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Connection to database from sqlalchemy:

```
DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@db:5432/db_ok'

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    # command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    # volumes:
    #   - .:/usr/src/db_ok
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_ok
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR ./app
COPY ./app ./app
COPY ./utils/google.deb ./app/utils
COPY ./utils/chromedriver ./app/utils
COPY req.txt req.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -r req.txt
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

**But it works for windows**

how i can fix this problem?

Comment: Is the database container actually starting up?  What you show here seems okay – you have the right hostname, you don't have mismatched `networks:`, you have a `depends_on:` block that should at least prevent this DNS error.

Comment: @DavidMaze, now another error: connection to server at "db" (172.18.0.2), port 5432 failed: Connection refused

Comment: The "db" side of things looks fine.  There isn't enough data here to reproduce things on the "web" side.  It is just files referring to other files, which we don't have.

Comment: You would need to attach the DB container's logs for us to know if anything is actually wrong with the DB itself.